# Monitor for file greater than 1 hour old

Tags: windows, dos

I need to be able to determine if a file is older than one hour and if so, email, text, or page to notify that our process has started.   I need any file that ends with .eob

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime date = File.GetCreationTime(str_Path);
str_path is the path of the .eob file.

Then compare date variable with DateTime.Now()

and if its greater than 1 hour send your email or whatever you want to do next

EDIT

To accomplish this you will have to make a small c#/vb .Net application that will, when compiled, make a .exe. Then you can schedukle a job in windows to execute your small app.

Comment: There can be other files other than .eob  Is there a way to specify only *.eof

Comment: Yes, when you query your directory to get the files from it you can specify *.eob Have a look at the System.IO library in .Net. Especially the File and the Directory object. There is plenty of exemple on google or msdn to show you great example of what you are trying to accomplish.